# make a div inside a list item clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, html-lists

I am working on a project to display a bookmarks page and part of what I want to do is keep the description and toggle features for each bookmark hidden until the bookmark is clicked. I want to keep it simple with an add/removeClass() to decide if the rest of the bookmark-info is showing. I also want to only allow one to be open at a time but before I can do that I need my bookmarks clickable first.

I've started with making the bookmark-titles a button but would like to change it from this for styling purposes.

I'm not calling upon the bookmark correctly because it won't console.log anything on the bookmark button click. Take a look keeping in mind im only including 2 functions of my code. I declare for the content to be added later and I call the functions at the bottom of my js:

```js
const generateItemElement = function (item) { //item is the definition of the current object and all
    let itemTitle = `<span class="bookmark bookmark_filtered">${item.title}${item.rating}</span>`; //affects filtered items

    //REMEMBER TO ADD DELETE FUNCTION AND ICON
    return `
        <li class="js-bookmark" data-item-id="${item.id}">
            <button type='button' class="js-bookmarkHead">
                ${itemTitle}
            </button>
            <div id="js-bookmarkInfo" class='hidden'>
                <button class="js-item-delete">Delete</button>
           
            
                <button class="visit">
                    <a href="${item.url}"target=blank>Visit</a>
                </button>
                <div class="description">
                    ${item.desc}
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>`;

};


const handleToggleExpandClick = function () {
    $('#bookmarkHead').click(() => {
            $('#js-bookmarkInfo').removeClass('hidden');
            render();
        });

};
```

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```js
$('#bookmarkHead').click(() => {
```

Sets up the click-handler which needs to be done after the bookmark elements have been added to the DOM, so the way your code is structured right now, you would have to call `handleToggleExpandClick` after `generateItemElement`. Check out [delegated event handlers](https://api.jquery.com/on/) in order to workaround this issue.

However, the selector you have specified `$('#bookmarkHead')` is incorrect, it should be `$('.js-bookmarkHead')` since you're using the class attribute. Also, id attributes have to be unique and I'm guessing you have multiple bookmarks so I would not use that attribute for `js-bookmarkInfo`.

You could also change your click handler to something like:

```js
$('.js-bookmarkHead').click(function() { // <- not using arrow style signature
  // $(this) will refer to the clicked .js-bookmarkHead element
  $(this).next().toggleClass('hidden');
  render();
});
```